# Change Base SDK from iOS 6.0 to iOS 5.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was given an old iPad application to repair and to make it work on iOS 6. It is supposed to work perfectly on iOS 5.0.

But as I am compiling using iOS 6 as the base SDK, the application does not work on perfectly on iOS 5 anymore (even on iPad 5.0 Simulator).

I think it would be better to work with the iOS 5.0 base SDK. But I may be wrong.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Apple won't allow uploading apps with iOS 5 sdk. It should be the latest version!

Comment: You need to build it with iOS6.

Comment: You might want to specify what "the application does not work on perfectly on iOS 5" means in your case. Does it crash? If so, is there something being logged to the console about missing symbols or the like? Is the behavior more subtly different from what it was before? If so, in what ways? With more detail, we might be able to help you get this working in iOS 6.0, with a target of 5.0.

Comment: The only thing that's not working now is coverflow, I think they used OpenFlow when they created this app. Since the first test, the images did not appeared, even on iOS5. The cover flow is here, because when I touch on the place it is supposed to be, it opens what it has to. I just do not have any pictures. It stays empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the code is not using any iOS 6 only features. For instance, some of the new Objective-C literal syntax for accessing array elements is not available for use in iOS 5 even though some of the other new literal syntax changes *are* available in iOS 5.

Comment: I passed everything on iOS 6.0, even the deployment target, and I got 50 more warnings. I will begin by correcting all of them, maybe my answer will be there.

Comment: specifcally, subscripting will not work in iOS5 without adding methods  to the relevant objects using categories.